# Cannot download S3 bucket contents even though bucket policy allows this ip address

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file from my S3 bucket using one of my ec2 instances using curl and wget. I set up my bucket policy originally as

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "HelpGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::name_of_bucket/*"],
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "10.152.0.0/15",
                    "10.154.0.0/17",
                    "10.154.128.0/17"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

I then went to my instance that has the ip address 10-152-17-111 and did wget/curl with and without quotes

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/name_of_bucket/my_file.tar.gz
```

This gave me a 403
    curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/name_of_bucket/my_file.tar.gz

This gave me a 403

Now I changed my policy so that all s3 actions were available and my specific ip address was included

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "HelpGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::name_of_bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::name_of_bucket/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "10.152.0.0/15",
                    "10.154.0.0/17",
                    "10.154.128.0/17",
                    "10.152.17.111/32"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

I then ran the same commands, again with and without quotes:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/name_of_bucket/my_file.tar.gz
```

returns 403

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/name_of_bucket/my_file.tar.gz
```

returns 403

I have no idea what to do next, I just want to download my files from my s3 bucket. I should have permissions, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your s3 bucket policy, you provide allowed IPs in the `10/8` range.  But the s3 endpoints you're hitting aren't on your private `10/8` network; they have public IPs, and your request will be seen as originating from *your* public IP, not your private IP.

https://wtfismyip.com/text is one way to determine your public IP.  Obviously this is going to change depending on what network you're on, and will also apply to anyone else on that network, which are 2 of the reasons why IP based permissions are not a common way of granting S3 access.  If your s3 content is truly public and not confidential, you might consider attaching a `public-read` ACL to the objects themselves at upload time; then the bucket policy is irrelevant.

**tl;dr** : put your public IP in the policy, not your private IP.

Comment: Changing it to a public ip address worked. I can't believe I missed that, thank you!